# How to inpect the registers value on a specific call stack frame in windbg

Tags: windbg, callstack

I'm investigating a Windows dump file in WinDBG. I can switch the call stack frame by command .frame, but I found that the registers always contain the last context.
I mean, if it is possible to restore the context which belongs to a specific call stack frame that is not the top one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're debugging an x64 target, you can use:

```
.frame /r
```

To view the registers in the frame. This information is based on the unwind data in the image, so it's pretty reliable. You can also change the context with:

```
.frame /c
```

On the x86, there's no unwind information so this trick doesn't work. .frame will still show you something for the registers, but it's not as likely to be correct (it will basically only be correct by luck).

Comment: Got it. I can only find the registers in stack indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

try findthis.py, which is kind of obtaining the CFI (Call Frame Info) by disassembling the prolog of each frame in the callstack.

http://nick.luckygarden.org/find-this-ptr-within-a-callstack-in-a-dump-file/